# TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined + Jest + NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, babel-jest

I am using jest for unit testing in of nodeJS APIs. I have installed jest and added it to the script in package.json as well. But facing the issue:

FAIL api/test/math.test.js
● Test suite failed to run

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

 at module.exports (node_modules/request-promise-core/configure/request2.js:34:48)
 at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/request-promise-native/lib/rp.js:15:1)
 at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/jsdom/lib/api.js:6:17)

 Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
 Tests:       0 total
 Snapshots:   0 total
 Time:        0.091s
 Ran all test suites.
 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
 npm ERR! errno 1
 npm ERR! chain-analytics@1.0.0 test: `jest`
 npm ERR! Exit status 1
 npm ERR!
 npm ERR! Failed at the sample-project@1.0.0 test script.
 npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Below are my sample classes for the same :

math.js :

```
  const sum = (a, b) => a + b
  const mul = (a, b) => a * b
  const sub = (a, b) => a - b
  const div = (a, b) => a / b

  export default { sum, mul, sub, div };
```

math.test.js :

```
 const  {sum, mul, sub, div}  = require("./math")

 test("Adding 1 + 1 equals 2", () => {
   expect(sum(1, 1)).toBe(2)
 })
 test("Multiplying 1 * 1 equals 1", () => {
   expect(mul(1, 1)).toBe(1)
 })
 test("Subtracting 1 - 1 equals 0", () => {
   expect(sub(1, 1)).toBe(0)
 })
 test("Dividing 1 / 1 equals 1", () => {
   expect(div(1, 1)).toBe(1)
 })
```

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Export uses import. `module.exports` will give you `require`.

**Modules & Require**

You should change `math.js` either:

```
module.exports = { sum, mul, sub, div };
```

For the code:

```
const {sum, mul, sub, div} = require("./math");
```

**Import / Export**

Or you should use:

```
import { sum, mul, sub, div } from "./math";
```

For the code:

```
export default { sum, mul, sub, div };
```

It's just the right combination.

Answer (score 1):

Change your exports in `math.js` to be:

```
module.exports = { sum, mul, sub, div };
```

NodeJS doesn't support the ES6 import/export syntax I believe.

Comment: Depends on the NodeJS version, no? :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48139882/jestjs-tests-failing-internally-with-request-promise-core

Looks like others are having a similar issue. Maybe related to the `request-promise-core` library?

Comment: How I can debug that which dependency is creating the problem. While debugging I am not seeing any dependency related error.

Comment: @A.P Worst way, try removing one by one and check.

Comment: It is a sample file in one big project. It has so many dependencies that It will be difficult to remove one by one and check :(

Comment: Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

`q.js` :

```js
function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

module.exports = sum;
```

`q.test.js` :

```js
const sum = require('../src/q');

test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
  const result = sum(1, 3);
  expect(result).toBe(3);
});
```

Even this gives an error, this is exactly copied from the `jest` documentation! 
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started

[image]